# SQL Statement Ignored missing expression in Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-insert

I am writing the below trigger where i am getting the error while to trying to insert the value for this field `FIELD_OLD_VALUE,FIELD_NEW_VALUE`. I have to insert the value for this fields based on Select query but i am getting the error as `SQL Statement Ignored ORA-000936 missing expression in Oracle trigger`. I dont want to use variable for field `FIELD_OLD_VALUE,FIELD_NEW_VALUE` because i have written the insert statement only for `ENV_ID` field in this question and i have many other fields to add in this trigger. So its difficult to decalre variable and maintain for each and every field.

```
create or replace TRIGGER RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION."TRG_TRK_KPI_DEFINITION" AFTER UPDATE ON RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  --NEU
  IF NOT  :old.ENV_ID=:new.ENV_ID THEN
    INSERT INTO RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.FIELD_TRACKING  (FIELD_TRACKING_ID,TABLE_NAME,TABLE_ID, FIELD_NAME,FIELD_OLD_VALUE,FIELD_NEW_VALUE,USER_ID, TIMESTAMP)
    VALUES (FIELD_TRACKING_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'KPI_DEFINITION',:new.KPI_DEF_ID,'Environment',to_char(Select NAME FROM ENVIRONMENT WHERE ENV_ID =:old.ENV_ID),to_char(Select NAME FROM ENVIRONMENT WHERE ENV_ID =:new.ENV_ID),:new.LAST_UPDATED_BY,:new.LAST_UPDATED_DATE );
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use subqueries as parameters you need to wrap them in extra parentheses:

```
to_char((Select NAME FROM ENVIRONMENT WHERE ENV_ID =:old.ENV_ID))
```